# LINQ - Result not null if querying a nonexistent element

Tags: c#, linq, null

Currently, i have a table with the data Fruits, grade and price. The grade available in my table are **A** , **B** and **C**. *Please look at the code snippet*. As what you can see, i put **D** in the `where` filter. I suppose the `query` will be null. But after i run the code, the program prompt the "Not Null? WTH?". So, may i know whats in the `query` and how to detect the **D** if it's not in the table?

p/s: i'm newbie

C# code snippet:

```
 var query = (from p in db
              where p.grade == "D"
              select p.price).ToArray();

 if (query == null)
              System.Console.WriteLine("You get Null in the query");
 else if (query != null)
              System.Console.WriteLine("Not Null? WTH?");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing `ToArray`, it will never be null. You may check the length.

```
if(query.Length <= 0)
```

Or even better if you do:

```
var query = (from p in db
            where p.grade == "D"
            select p.price).Count();

if(query > 0)
```

or

```
var ifItemExist = (from p in db
                   where p.grade == "D"
                   select p.price).Any();
```

Or shorter:

```
var ifItemExist = db.Any(p=> p.grade == "D");
```

Comment: oh ya! array.length....... Damn, my brain is stuck in the noon. Thanks for the solution. +1 C=

Answer (score 3):

You don't get null because this method will still return an array. The array will be empty, but the array will not be null. (This is in fact why null exists... it is to differentiate between a "zero" value and the absence of a value.

If you want to test if there are any elements in the result you can use:

```
if (query.Any())
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is not null, it's returning an empty array which is different from null.

alternately, you can do this,

```
int query = (from p in db
              where p.grade == "D"
              select p.price).Count();

 if (query > 0)
 {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Found");
 }
  else
 {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
 }
```